# eclipse software installation - contacting software sites repeats for longer duration

Tags: eclipse, updates, eclipse-oxygen, update-site

Trying to update the Eclipse oxygen software it takes while, how to optimize the update time or any issue in my eclipse software. In **Eclipse IDE -> help->check for updates**

Answer (score 0):

One or more update sites are probably not available. Try to (temporarily) **deactivate some update site, except `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/`** in ***Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Availaible Software Sites*** by unchecking them.

Comment: Thanks Howlger, yes it's an temporary issue with an update site. After removing unused update sites it worked.